# How to make sure a chained logging statement is atomic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, method-chaining

I have a logging class which has `operator<<` overloaded. So I can do things like this:

```
oLogger << "Log this" << " and this" << " and " << 10 << endl;
oLogger`<< "Something else" << endl;
```

The logger does this without any problems. But, I want the logger object to be shared among threads. Then, I don't want it printing out something like this:

```
//LogFILE
Log this and this Something else
 and 10
```

So, I need to lock a whole chain of `operator<<`s. I am guessing this can be done with RAII, I haven't given it much thought yet. In the meantime, is there any traditional way of getting this done? (Except ending input with a manipulator?)

Comment: Is your logger thread safe? If it is you might get along with just building the string aside (consider something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469696/what-is-your-most-useful-c-c-utility/470999#470999) and logging a single `std::string`, but in general, follow @Nim advice and lock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slight alternative to Nim's answer:

Create

```
class LockedLog {
    static MutEx mutex; // global mutex for logging
    ScopedLock lock; // some scoped locker to hold the mutex
    Logger &oLogger; // reference to the log writer itself
public:
    LockedLog(Logger &oLogger) : oLogger(oLogger), lock(mutex) {}
    template <typename T>
    LockedLog &operator<<(const T &value) { oLogger << value; return *this; }
};
```

And either just do:

```
LockedLog(oLogger) << "Log this" << " and this " << " and " << 10 << endl;
```

Or change `Logger::operator<<` to normal method, call this method in `LockedLog::operator<<`, add cast-operator to `Logger`:

```
operator LockedLog() { return LockedLog(*this); }
```

and that should add locking to your current code.

**Update:** That locks across all the calls to `operator<<` and *may* even lock around evaluation of their arguments (depends on whether compiler will evaluate left or right argument first and it may choose). To reduce that, one could:

```
class LockedLog {
    static MutEx mutex; // global mutex for logging
    std::stringstream buffer; // temporary formatting buffer;
    Logger &oLogger; // reference to the log writer itself
public:
    LockedLog(Logger &oLogger) : oLogger(oLogger), lock(mutex) {}
    template <typename T> 
    LockedLog &operator<<(const T &value) { buffer << value; return *this; }
    ~LockedLog() { ScopedLock lock(mutex); oLogger << buffer.str() << std::flush; }
};
```

But the `stringstream` adds another overhead.

Comment: Same critic that for Nim's answer: you're locking longer than necessary.

Comment: Indeed. It would be possible to reduce the locking by using a temporary buffer (stringstream). That would add another overhead though, so depending on how many threads there are it may or may not pay off.

Comment: The `operator<<`does not work with `endl`. It gives the following error: "LockedLog::operator <<": cannot deduce type argument as function argument is ambiguous. I changed it to `Logger &operator<<(const T& value) { cout << value; return oLogger; }`, but I am not sure, if this behaves as expected.

Comment: @JohannesGerer: Yes, it does work (except in the last variant with stringstream), because temporaries are only destroyed at end of statement. The other option is to add a `LockedLog &operator<<(ostream& ( *pf )(ostream&))` overload as ostream itself has, with the advantage that it will work if you want to start with a manipulator too.

Comment: @JohannesGerer: I said it does work except in the variant with stringstream, but it would work in that variant too, just you have to return the stringstream there. (Oh, and the stringstream variant should probably flush too, because you can't flush the Logger there; adding.)

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use a macro, i.e.

```
#define LOG(x) \
{\
  <acquire scoped lock> \
  oLogger << x; \
}
```

then

```
LOG("Log this" << " and this" << " and " << 10 << endl);
```

I've also done it using the manipulator approach that you mention above, however the problem is that you need to have `operator<<` implemented for all the types (i.e. can't use the standard operators that exist)

EDIT: to reduce the time the lock is held, consider something like this:

```
#define LOG(x) \
{\
  std::ostringstream str; \
  str << x; \       // the streaming happens in local scope, no need for lock
  oLogger.write(str.str()); \ // ensure the write method acquires a lock
}
```

Comment: +1, atomicity can only be ensured by means of locks, and moreover, without locks you might even be causing unexpected results (maybe UB?) depending on the implementation of the logger (is it reentrant? does it use global state?)

Comment: `LOG("current context: " << context.dump())` means that you're blocking logging for a very long period of time if `dump` performs a lot of computation. It'd be better to separate the formatting phase from the logging, only the latter requires locking.

Comment: @Matthieu, agreed, however it is trivial to change the above macro to stream to a temporary `stringstream` for example and then write the result to `oLogger` - the point was to highlight that it's the locking that is important...

Comment: I agree it's trivial, it's nonetheless important. As for the locking, I don't know if there are good implementations of lock-free queues for multiple customers. I think FF did it by combining multiple SPSC lock-free queues.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the best solution is to write a class `buffer` so that

```
buffer(oLogger) << "Log this" << " and this" << " and " << 10 << endl;
```

creates a temporary buffer object, captures and formats the output and writes it to oLogger in its destructor. This is trivially done by wrapping a `stringstream`. Because every thread has its own buffers, formatting is independent.

For extra fanciness, `buffer::~buffer` can use several different mechanisms to prevent thread-unsafe access of `oLogger`. You assumed that `operator<<` calls from multiple threads might be interleaved. In fact, it's worse; they can be concurrent. You could get "LSoogm ethhiinsg else". Makeing sure that only one `buffer` flushes to `oLogger` at a time prevents this.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use expression templates here.

The main idea is that it's bloody stupid to acquire the lock during the formatting phase, especially since there might be function calls during this formatting.

You need to use two different phases:

- format the log
- atomically post the log

This can be accomplished with expression templates:

1. First call to `Logger::operator<<` yields a `LoggerBuffer` that embeds a reference to `Logger`.
2. Subsequent calls are performed on `LoggerBuffer` which deals with all the formatting mess
3. Upon destruction of `LoggerBuffer` (at the end of the statement), it locks `Logger`, pass the formatted string, and unlocks (unless you've got a lock-free queue or something)

Answer (score 1):

As I have to internationalize logs, I prefer things like :

```
oLogger << myAutosprintf(_("My wonderful %s ! I have %d apples"), name, nbApple);
```

It is way better for translation :) And it will solve your problem. `_()` is a shortcut for the translation stuff.

You can use [gnu::autosprintf](http://doc.gnu-darwin.org/libasprintf/autosprintf.html), [boost.format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/format/index.html) (thanks to Jan Huec), or write your own.

my2c

*NB: Edited after good remarks (was too fast, thank you for the comments). I have erased the wrong "first part" statement*

Comment: Even if it is `operator<<` is thread safe (assume internal locking) that does not guarantee that if two threads try to log the message in the question they output won't be interleaved: "Log this and this Log this and this and and ..."

Comment: I don't think your first statement is correct, the result of the first call the `operator<<` is then used for the second call and so forth, so it does matter. You may acquire the lock in your first call, the problem is when to release it (hence the requirement of the manipulator)

Comment: @david, Nim: thanks for the remarks. my point was mainly to use a class that build the message ... I wonder if `()` could do the trick ...  `oLogger << (x << y << z << endl);`

Comment: The `gnu::autosprintf` looks interesting. But it is not type-safe. The boost.format  (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/format/index.html) is. It is slower, because it goes through `stringstream`, but on the other hand that allows it to format objects with custom `operator<<` too.